# Change combobox value using jquery

Tags: jquery, class, combobox

I am working with a web program that publishes a combobox to a default "all" value seen in the below code:

```
<select size="1" name="W45_Sl" id="W45_Sl" style="cursor: pointer;">
<option class="selected" value="u;" selected="1">(All)</option>
<option class=" nAll" value="h6512;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA">2/22/2013</option>
<option class=" nAll" value="h6511;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA">2/21/2013</option>
<option class=" nAll" value="h6510;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA">2/20/2013</option>
</select>
```

When you change the value of the combobox in the web page, it alters the code like the below, to manipulate a target object:

```
<select size="1" name="W45_Sl" id="W45_Sl" style="cursor: pointer;">
<option class="" value="u;" selected="1">(All)</option>
<option class=" nAll" value="h6512;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA">2/22/2013</option>
<option class=" nAll selected" value="h6511;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA">2/21/2013</option>
<option class=" nAll" value="h6510;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA">2/20/2013</option></select>
```

What I want to do through jquery is alter the combobox on load to be a default value such that it changes the target object, I wrote the below jquery to change the combobox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $("#W45_Sl").removeClass("selected");});</script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $("#W45_Sl").val("h6511;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA");});</script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $("#W45_Sl").addClass(" nAll selected");});</script>
```

My problem is that the combobox will reflect the updated value of "h6511;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA""2/21/2013", **but the class code and target object do not change.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `<script>$(document).ready(function() {` for each statement?

Comment: ** nAll selected** try to remove the space from the start.

**$(document).ready(function() { $("#W45_Sl").addClass("nAll selected");});**

Comment: undefined - that makes it the jquery run once the document has been completed. If there is a better way to make code run on the page load please let me know.

Comment: UnKnow - the space is defined by the program it has to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function()
{
    $("#W45_Sl").removeClass("selected").attr("value","h6511;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA").addClass("nAll selected");      
});
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work, it changes the value in the box but does not change the classes to force the the target to change. I might be missing something in the program code.

Comment: @KP_EDIT you want to get option with value h6511;73D71A62420B4A8431F3DF84098216AA and then remove class and then add class to other..?